# Unwind a Modal UINavigationController to another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to segue back to another `UIViewController` after modally presenting a `UINavigationController` and with it a `root ViewController`. What I want to happen is for a button to unwind from the root VC of the `UINavigationController` and return to the initial `UIViewController` that presented it. I have the unwind method written in the destination VC and button is hooked up to the Exit point of the VC. But when I press the button, nothing happens. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? Any advice is appreciated.

Storyboard:

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnvhu.png)

Code:

```
-(IBAction)unwindToClockView:(UIStoryboardSegue*)sender;
{
    NSLog(@"Back to Clock View");
}
```

Additional code can be found here: https://github.com/xinkecf35/TrafficAlarmClock

Comment: On which button click it should unwind?

Comment: Connecting `gentleWakeSwitch` with `unwindToClockView` on `exit` worked for me.

Comment: Oh sorry, it should be the button labeled back in the navigation bar area, the switch is for something else.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have a solution. It just involves programmatically calling a method trigger by the button that outright dismisses the view controller. The method is below.

```
-(IBAction)dismissSettings:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:TRUE completion:nil];
}
```

If anyone can present a solution that uses Storyboards as well, it will be greatly appreciated.